# Are sealed classes enforced in Java and, if yes, how?

Tags: java, class, scala, interop, sealed

It is possible to define `sealed` classes in Scala, which are basically `final` except if the sub-classing happens in the same file.

It seems that the JVM doesn't allow `final` class bytecode *and* subclasses of it.

Considering that there is no "notion" of source file in the bytecode, how is this restriction enforced?

Therefore, how can `javac` prevent a Scala `sealed` class from being sub-classed in Java?

Comment: So just to clarify, you're asking if it's possible to have `sealed` classes in Scala code run on a JVM (**not** whether it's possible, in the Java *language*, to have something akin to `sealed` classes). Right?

Comment: What do you mean by "It seems that the JVM doesn't allow final class bytecode"? Isn't there bytecode marking a class final?

Comment: @pedrofurla: AFAIK the JVM doesn't allow sub-classes of classes marked `final` in the bytecode? Or is this restriction only enforced in `javac`?

Comment: @T. J. Crowder: No, I want to know if the bytecode of `sealed` classes prevent it from being sub-classed in Java code.

Comment: I don't believe Java supports sealed. If it can be sub-classes in the same file, it can be sub-classed anywhere unless the constructor private. Scala must have its own restriction.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The restriction is enforced for Scala source by scalac at compile time. The resulting binary class definitions don't have the JVMs final flag set so, as you've probably guessed by now, the sealed restriction will not be enforced by javac when Java sources are compiled against  Scala binaries.

Comment: Would it (e.g. by a package check in the `sealed class` constructor) be possible to enforce it on the Java/JVM side, even if it's only at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

How about using a private constructor for the class you would like to seal, and then create public final static inner classes that extends that class. Then you get a fixed set of subclasses at compile time that can't be extended further. The base class with the private constructor subsequently serves as a path to reach those inner classes, but is in itself impossible to extend and implement elsewhere.